Two-site mutual information for locally purified tensor network ansatz
I came across this reference for modelling the thermal ensemble $\rho_T = Tr_Q|\Psi_T\rangle \langle \Psi_T|$, where $Q$ is an auxiliary degree of freedom encoding the thermal bath. Equation 38 suggests forming a bond tensor along the virtual leg of the two middle sites of the chain, perfoming SVD to get the singular values for the first term. The second term is obtained by forming a bond tensor of the middle site (either left or right of the chain) along the $Q$ leg and then SVD. Is that correct?
In addition, I'm also interested in calculating the two-site mutual information (TSMI). For MPS, the implementation is quite forward (see reference Eq.31-36). I'm not sure how to generalize this to the LPTN ansatz. There is an implementation of this calculation in TeNPy. But I would really appreciate an explanation in TN diagrams. I think TSMI can again be written as a sum of contribution from the virtual and $Q$ leg.
